# How to pass list of generic fields with their corresponding first operator to Aggregation.group method

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to write a generic code for aggregation using mongoTempalte and Aggregation.group() method. So I have the problem of passing generic fields into the group method with the first() operator

here is my demo native query as follows:

```
    db.subscriberProfile.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$usage_history"},
{ "$group" : { "_id" :"$_id" ,"birthdate" : { "$first":"$birthdate"} , "category" : { "$first":"$category"} , "control_group" : { "$first":"$control_group"}  , "sumOfTotalUsage" : { "$sum" :{"$cond": [ { "$gte" :[ "$usage_history.date" ,   ISODate( "2017-01-13T10:43:55.306Z")] }, "$usage_history.total_usage", 0]}}}},
 { "$match" : { "$and" : [ { "birthdate" : { "$lte" :  ISODate( "2017-07-12T10:43:55.306Z")}} , { "birthdate" : { "$gte" :  ISODate( "1917-07-12T10:20:35.306Z")}} , { "category" : { "$in" : [ "Prepaid"]}} , { "control_group" : false} , { "sumOfTotalUsage" : { "$gte" : 0}}]}}])
```

And here is my Sample code in Java.

```
UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("usage_history");
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()])).sum("usage_history.total_usage").as("sumOfTotalUsage");
```

I just want to know how to add multiple fields  in group operation with $first operator.
So, Is there any way to pass list of fields with list of first operator to the group method.
Thanks,

Comment: Good luck, we will keep fingers crossed for you! We are glad you shared this with us :) I think that this would be more proper to be pased on facebook or twitter. In meanwhile here is  something for you: [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This site is not intend to write your code

Comment: Something like `Aggregation.group(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()])).first("birthdate").as("birthdate").first("category").as("category").sum("usage_history.total_usage").as("sumOfTotalUsage");`

Comment: Thanks for comment. @Veeram
but I have different -2 fields in different scenarios, so I can not write their name hard coded in first() attribute.  I required a generic way to solve this issue.

Comment: Np.  You need to be really clear as to what your expectation is. Your last update only asks how to specify multiple fields with $first operator. Please take some time and consider editing your post/ title to specify what you need including both scenarios and all other relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,I hope this will help you

```
UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("usage_history");

  BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$_id");

  for (String string : fields) {

   object.append(string, new BasicDBObject("$first", "$" + string));
  }

  object.append("total", new BasicDBObject("$sum", new BasicDBObject("$cond",
    new Object[] { new BasicDBObject("$gte", new Object[] { "$usage_history.date", calendarMin.getTime() }),
      "$usage_history.total_usage", 0 })));

  BasicDBObject groupObject = new BasicDBObject("$group", object);
  DBObject groupOperation = (DBObject) groupObject;

  MatchOperation matchMain = Aggregation
    .match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()])));

  Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwind, new CustomGroupOperation(groupOperation),
    matchMain);
```

Comment: It is running but I was looking for the solution through Aggregation.group, not by BasicDBObject